# How to change the default MathJax renderer on Math.SE?

Tags: support, mathjax

It's easy enough to right-click a formula and change it to something else like "Common HTML", but as soon as I reload it reverts back to "HTML-CSS"... how do I change the default renderer?

Comment: Are you blocking cookies from cdn.mathjax.org by any chance?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: nope it doesn't seem like it...

Comment: My understanding is that the setting is supposed to stick, albeit on a site-by-site basis.  Thus one is supposed to be able to set the default renderer for Math.SE and have a different one for (say) SciComp.SE.  I've assumed Meta.Math.SE was also a separate default, but you've got me curious to check how things really work.

Comment: I did the experiment.  Here at Meta.Math.SE my math rendering defaults to HTML-CSS.  Went to the main site and found the same setting there.  Changed it to Common HTML.  Came back to meta (navigating, not back paging) and confirmed the default here is still HTML-CSS.  Navigated back to Math.SE and found the change of default renderer to Common HTML is still in effect.

Comment: @hardmath: Strange. It's sticking for me in M.SE on incognito, but not outside... I'll track this down, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @hardmath: I cleared my Math.SE cookies and local storage now it works, go figure...

Answer (score 1):

I cleared my Math.SE cookies and local storage now it works. Go figure...

#### Update:

For Chrome, on other sites that don't allow you to right-click and choose (cough, Quora), try running something like this in the Background Page console of an extension that has `chrome.cookies` write access, such as Privacy Badger:

```
chrome.cookies.set({
    url: "https://www.example.com/",
    name: "mjx.menu",
    value: "renderer%3ACommonHTML",
    expirationDate: 2000000000
}, function (cookie) { console.log(cookie); })
```